# why it is showing error ? vb.net database connectivity

Tags: database, vb.net, oracle, oledb

i am using visual studio 2010 windows form application and i have connected my oracle 11g database throught oledb ..in my application and i want to insert userid and password details to database from my application but it is showing 
One or more errors occurred during processing of command.
ORA-00936: missing expression
pls help ..:'(
my code is :

```
[con.ConnectionString = "Provider=MSDAORA;Data Source=ebuddiess-PC;User ID=ebuddiess;Password=password"
    com = New OleDbCommand("Insert into userinfo(userid,pwd) values(@userid,@pwd)", con)
    obj1 = New OleDbParameter("@userid", OleDb.OleDbType.LongVarChar)
    obj1.Value = TextBox1.Text
    com.Parameters.Add(obj1)
    obj2 = New OleDbParameter("@pwd", OleDb.OleDbType.LongVarChar)
    obj2.Value = TextBox2.Text
    com.Parameters.Add(obj2)
    con.Open()
    com.ExecuteNonQuery()
    MsgBox("inserted")
    con.Close][1]()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong, it must be like this:

```
com = New OleDbCommand("Insert into userinfo (userid,pwd) values (?,?)", con)
obj1 = New OleDbParameter("userid", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar)
obj1.Value = TextBox1.Text
com.Parameters.Add(obj1)
obj2 = New OleDbParameter("pwd", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar)
```

Comment: @PuneetKumar, in this case please accept my answer.

Comment: I dont know how to accept ..what it mean m new here